# When did C-3PO meet BB-8 first time?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, c-3po, bb-8

This is the line C-3PO speaks when he meets BB-8 in *The Force Awakens* (2015):

> C-3PO: Come along, BB-8, quickly. Yes, I must get my proper arm
> reinstalled.

That means they know each other even before.

Comment: Why does it mean they must know each other before? It’s quite obvious it isn’t his arm. That said they’re both in the Rebellion so I’d be surprised if they hadn’t seen each other before.

Comment: C3P0 could just access data bank of rebellion to get info on BB-8.